# Array shifting and rearranging

Tags: arrays, c

So I am trying to search an array for a value and if found I want to remove that value from the array and place it at the front of the array shifting the rest before its position down 1. "Tag" is the value being searched. My results don't exactly seem to be right. Not the best at this hoping someone can explain what I did wrong and how I should fix it. This is in C.

```
         if (replacement == 1) { 
//Search arrays for value (tag)
      int j,k;
      //MRU hit
       for(j=0; j<=lines; j++){
         if(MRU[j] == tag){
          printf("Hit!"" \n");
          hits++;
           h = 1;
           k=j;
            temp1 = MRU[j - 1];  
            for(k = j; k > 0; k--) { 
            MRU[k] = MRU[k - 1];  
            MRU[0] = tag;
            }
           break;
         
           }
         }
```

Comment: You need some more consistent indentation so that humans can follow your code without requiring unnecessary cognitive strain. Claims like "my results don't seem right" need to be supported by an actual example of what input you have and what output you get. It looks like you're on the right track, but you should not do `MRU[0] = tag;` in that inner loop, because that will overwrite the first value of the array before all values have been shifted. Do it after the loop.

Comment: So the Value of tag changes and for each value I want to search the array for it. If the value is there I want to move that value from its location to the front of the array. If the value is not there I want to add it to the front of the array shifting the rest back. I am noticing (after I have moved MRU[0] = tag; outside of the loop) on the very first few searches It somehow is finding the value there even when the array should be empty and later it will find a value still there that should have been shifted out. I made a test input with only 2 viable and they match every time.

Comment: Test input was like [1,2,2,2,.... a lot more 2's....,1 and the hit every time.  should have at least 3 misses. two at the beginning and 1 at the end.

Comment: Please don't describe input like this. Just show examples of actual input. Show actual output. Edit information into your question, not the comments. Show your whole program. You have a possible off-by-one error depending on what the variable `lines` represents.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include<stdio.h>  
  
#define N 5  
  
int main()  
{  
    int a[N], i, temp, pos, dir;  
  
    printf("Enter %d integer numbers\n", N);  
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);  
  
    printf("Enter the number of positions to shift\n");  
    scanf("%d", &pos);  
  
    printf("Enter the direction of shifting ...\n");  
    printf("LEFT: 1 and RIGHT: 0\n");  
    scanf("%d", &dir);  
  
    while(pos)  
    {  
        if(dir)  
        {  
            temp = a[0];  
            for(i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)  
                a[i] = a[i + 1];  
  
            a[N - 1] = temp;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            temp = a[N - 1];  
            for(i = N - 1; i > 0; i--)  
                a[i] = a[i - 1];  
  
            a[0] = temp;  
        }  
  
        pos--;  
    }  
  
    printf("Array after shift operation ...\n");  
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);  
  
    printf("\n");  
  
    return 0;  
}
```

I don't quite understand your issue because I am still a beginner in C programming but, This might be helpful to you
https://technotip.com/8964/c-program-to-shift-elements-of-an-array-by-n-position/